# Virtual Box Error - (VERR_NOT_SUPPORTED) for \Users\name\Downloads\xubuntu-12.10-desktop-i386.iso.torrent image file

Tags: virtualbox

Once I imported the VM, I pointed the CDROM at a Linux LiveCD which I found at http://preview.tinyurl.com/xubuntutorrent (Torrent). To set up the CDROM I selcted VM -> Settings -> Storagge -> Controller: IDE -> Empty. Then I clicked on the CD icon on the right. I selected choose a virtual disk and poited it to the Linux image I downloaded : xubuntu-12.10-desktop-i386.iso.torrent . However for some reason I am getting the following error. Pls help! Thanks! :D

Failed to open the optical disk file C:
\Users\name\Downloads\xubuntu-12.10-desktop-i386.iso.torrent
Could not get the storage of the medium ':C: 
\Users\name\Downloads\xubuntu-12.10-desktop-i386.iso.torrent'(VERR_NOT_SUPPORTED).

Result Code: VBOX_E_IPRT_ERROR (0x80BB0005)
Component: Medium
Interface: IMedium{05f2bbb6-a3a6-4fb9-9b49-6d0dda7142ac}
Callee:    IVirtualBox{fafa4e17-1ee2-4905-a10efe7c18bf5554}
Callee RC: VBOX_E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND
           (0x80BB0001)

Comment: Based on the error message, are you sure you're not pointing to the .torrent file instead of the downloaded .iso?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I downloaded the image file from the link but it has an extension of iso.torrent instead of just .iso. I am not sure how I can discard the .torrent at the end. How can I not point to the .torrent file instead of the downloaded .iso? When I go to another link provided in the spec to download a .iso file from this link: http://preview.tinyurl.com/xubuntuiso it says "The requested URL /ubuntu-iso/CDs-Xubuntu/12.10/release/xubuntu-12.10-desktop-i386.iso was not found on this server." Not sure how to download the image file with just a .iso extension. Pls clarify.

Comment: You may simply rename the file, there is no problem in doing that. But, ultimately, the extension is irrelevant, if the format is correct, VirtualBox should recognize it no matter what, unless you point to the wrong file, or maybe the image format isn't among the recognized ones. Try this, mount the image with some program like Daemon Tools so that it creates a virtual CD drive, and if successful, use that as the virtual CD drive.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply! However the answer provided by the user below worked :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to use a `.torrent` file as an image file. `.torrent` files allow Torrent clients to download files from peers on the internet.

You should get some torrent client like [Transmission](http://www.transmissionbt.com/download/) (also available [for Windows](http://sourceforge.net/projects/trqtw/)) in order to download your desired `.iso` file, and then use that one with VirtualBox.

PS: you can also use [this direct download link](http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/mirror/cdimage.ubuntu.com/xubuntu/releases/12.10/release/xubuntu-12.10-desktop-i386.iso) for getting Xubuntu 12.10 Desktop i386 as listed [here](http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/mirror/cdimage.ubuntu.com/xubuntu/releases/12.10/release/)

Comment: The above answer was very helpful! However, when I tried to download the iso image file from the direct download link provided it is taking too much time to download and has yet not completed. When I tried downloading the windows Transmission client and placed the torrent image file link in the open url area, it says GotMetadataFromURL:GotMetadataFromURL: Http Error 404: Not Found
http://torrent.ubuntu.com/xubuntu/releases/qu antal/release/desktop/xubuntu-12.10-desktop-i 386.iso.torrent. Not sure what is wrong in both cases..

Comment: Pls disregard the above comment; the transmission client download is working now! Thanks greatly for the helpful links and info!!